# MFC compare string

Tags: c++, mfc

```
sf.pTo = _T("D:\\Test2"); // it 's ok, you can move to folder Test2
CString m_to = EditCtrl_To.GetString();
sf.pTo = m_to;// EditCtrl_To is Edit Ctrol and it's value is "D:\\Test2"
```

I cannot move to folder Test2. 
And when I compare  _T("D:\Test2") & m_to, it is not equal. Why?

Please help me, thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: I think there are no stupid questions, so I raised your vote (now it is -1), but try to do some kind of research BEFORE you ask something.

Answer (score 1):

Basic C++:

If you assign a string and use a backslash \, you have to escape it like `c:\\test2`. Without it, you have a tab character in the string.

If you copy it from the edit control, this is what makes the difference, because the control did this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it does not work. I try run as below but it is alway not equal.Please help me. : CString t = _T("D:\\Test1\\*.*");
 
 if(t.CompareNoCase(t)){
  MessageBoxA(NULL, "Equal", "Status", MB_OK);
 }else{
  MessageBoxA(NULL, "Not Equal", "Status", MB_OK);
 }

Comment: You have to escape _every_ \ in your string! And I am not sure if CompareNoCase is designed to compare to itself.

Comment: Just looked it up: CompareNoCase returns 0 if equal, so you have to alter your if statement. Not that it makes any sense to ask if x==x.

Comment: I try: CString t1 = _T("D:\\Test1\\*.*");CString t2 = _T("D:\\Test1\\*.*"); if(t1.CompareNoCase(t2)){ MessageBoxA(NULL, "Equal", "Status", MB_OK); }else{ MessageBoxA(NULL, "Not Equal", "Status", MB_OK); }   but i still not equal. Can you help me explain?

Comment: Did you read my comments?
1. It has to be D:\\Test\\ *.*
2. CompareNoCase returns 0 if equal. 0 gets evaluated to false. --> if(!t1.CompareNoCase(....